# Remove characters from start and remove first instance of characters and text thereafter POWER QUERY

Tags: powerquery

I am trying to remove garbage data that we use in invoices just to make them unique adding prefix or suffix to the original invoice. Few of the example would be :

1. **000**123456**DP**
2. **MI**235252
3. **ABC**82856893**DP0**
4. **000**85838539**DP13**

What I am trying to achieve the below result in Power query but it removes either all the characters or all the numbers: -> this should the answer to the above examples.

1. 123456
2. 235252
3. 82856893
4. 85838539

Note: The numbers in between wouldn't have any character ( A - Z ) the only place it would have is either start ( can have 1, 2 or 3 characters ) or at the end like AB or AB13 which should be removed.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please [edit] your question with what have you tried so far. This information came from a database?, text file? - I'm not familiar with PowerQuery, but I think it uses some programming language for retrieve and manage data.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming data comes in Column1 of Table1, this seems to work.

1 Creates List of non-numeric and numeric characters

2 Locates position of first numeric character and removes everything before that along with any leading zeros

3 Locates position of first non-numeric character and removes that and everything after that

```
let
Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
#"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Column1", type text}}),
CharsToRemove = List.Transform({32,46,33..45,47,58..126}, each Character.FromNumber(_)),
CharsToKeep = List.Transform({48..57}, each Character.FromNumber(_)),
#"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Changed Type", "Custom", each Text.PositionOfAny([Column1],CharsToKeep ,0)),
#"Added Custom2" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Custom", "Custom2", each Text.TrimStart(Text.Middle([Column1],[Custom]),"0")),
#"Added Custom3" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Custom2", "Custom3", each Text.PositionOfAny([Custom2],CharsToRemove )),
#"Added Custom4" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Custom3", "Custom4", each if [Custom3]<0 then [Custom2] else Text.Start([Custom2],[Custom3]))
in #"Added Custom4"
```